# Can I bring alcohol purchased at a duty-free store back into the country after a short trip?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, duty-free

Is it allowed to purchase alcohol at a duty free store on the way out of the country, and bring it back when I return? Assuming I bring less than the personal exemption.

Specifically, I'm asking about crossing the U.S.-Canada border by bus.

I understand that U.S. citizens can bring into Canada

> 1.5 litres of wine, or 1.14 litres (40 ounces) of liquor, or 24 x 355 millilitres (12 ounces) cans or bottles (8.5 litres) of beer or ale.

and, after 48 hours, can return with

> Purchases [that] may include 1 litre of alcohol, 200 cigarettes (1 carton), and 100 cigars.

Further down on that page, it says

> Liquor, including spirits, wine and beer, in Canada is significantly more expensive than in the United States, so Americans going to Canada for a visit may want to stop at duty free for liquor that they will **consume while in Canada**.

Does this mean that I must consume all of the alcohol I purchase at duty free before crossing the border? If I declare it, will the bottle be labeled in a way that a border officer would even be able to distinguish it from another bottle purchased in Canada?

[Source](https://www.tripsavvy.com/what-visitors-can-buy-at-duty-free-1481856).

The U.S. CBP [info page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/customs-duty-info) doesn't clarify. To be clear, I will be in Canada for multiple days for a legitimate pleasure trip.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that I must consume all of the alcohol I purchase at duty free before crossing the border?

No. It means that if you're planning to drink alcohol in Canada, it could be a good idea to buy some at the DF store.

> will the bottle be labeled in a way that a border officer would even be able to distinguish it from another bottle purchased in Canada?

Yes, but more accurately, it will ***not*** be labeled like a bottle bought in Canada -- it will miss the tax sticker and importer's info. But that doesn't matter. If the alcohol you are carrying is within the limits, you don't need to declare it.